# executing a pathonscript via function return TypeError

Tags: python, exec

i have the following code for the execution of a pythonscript in a function:

```
def start_dokschrank(self):
    exec(open("/Externe/Besteller-Tool/dok_schrank.py").read())
```

This is the Error is get:

```
TypeError: Required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found
```

i dont understand that error? What is wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Damian

Comment: Please add dok_schrank.py script (lines where 'flags' is used). Error is in this script not in start_dokschrank method.

Comment: Is this supposed to be "Python"? Or is this something I don't know and whose tag does not exist? This is an actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're looking for the `os.open` function and not the built-in `open` function.

So:

```
import os
def start_dokschrank(self):
    exec(os.open("/Externe/Besteller-Tool/dok_schrank.py").read())
```

should work

But one comment: if you're running another python function you have better to import this function.